# How to generate a custom schema from a relation in Pig?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have a schema describing tf-idf values for words in various articles.
Its description looks like:

```
tfidf_relation: {word: chararray,id: bytearray,tfidf: double}
```

Here is an example of such data:

```
(cat,article_one,0.13515503603605478)
(cat,article_two,0.4054651081081644)
(dog,article_one,0.3662040962227032)
(apple,article_three,0.3662040962227032)
(orange,article_three,0.3662040962227032)
(parrot,article_one,0.13515503603605478)
(parrot,article_three,0.13515503603605478)
```

I want to get output in a form:
cat    article_one 0.13515503603605478, article_two 0.4054651081081644
and so on.
The question is, how do I make a relation from this which contains the word field and a tuple of id and tfidf fields?
Someting like this:

```
X = FOREACH tfidf_relation GENERATE word, (id, tfidf);
```

doesn't work. What is the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    t = LOAD 'input/file' USING PigStorage(',') as (word: chararray,id: bytearray,tfidf: double);
    u = group t by word;
    dump u;
```

The output will be

```
    (cat,{(cat,article_two,0.4054651081081644),(cat,article_one,0.13515503603605478)})
    (dog,{(dog,article_one,0.3662040962227032)})
    (apple,{(apple,article_three,0.3662040962227032)})
    (orange,{(orange,article_three,0.366204096222703)})
    (parrot,{(parrot,article_three,0.13515503603605478),
    (parrot,article_one,0.13515503603605478)})
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
X = FOREACH tfidf_relation GENERATE word, {(id, tfidf)};
```

This is probably what you need.

Comment: Wojtek, I've tried different forms of your solution - each time parsing error occurs at the symbol "{".

Comment: Okay, I think I have achieved this using Java routines embedding. But the correct Pig syntax (and possibility itself) is still of interest.

Comment: What about X.(id, tfidf) ? You can always group by word then flatten grouping (something like that if I remember), but probably much easier would be just to write quick UDF.